# Is there any way to see the number of thin clients connected to a server?

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I have developed an Apache Ignite thin client application. It successfully connects to the server and retrieves data without issues. However, on the server side, it shows the number of client connections as 0.

I want to monitor the number of thin clients connected to this server without using the Control Center of GridGain, as it is licensed.

Log:
Topology snapshot [ver=1, locNode=99dd7f2b, servers=1, clients=0, state=INACTIVE, CPUs=12, offheap=1.4GB, heap=1.5GB].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are [thin client metrics](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#ignite-thin-client-connector) and you are looking for `ActiveSessionsCount`. You need to register it as described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics-system#metric-registers).

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please. How to register the thin client metrics ?. I want to get the metrics (number of thin clients, number of servers and memory usage of servers etc..)from server side and display it in the client side. Sorry I'm new to ignite. TIA

Comment: Please take a look at the following example https://github.com/GridGain-Demos/ignite-metrics-demo
Be aware that logs and metrics are two different things. In your opening question you shared a log record with general information. But metrics can be obtained dynamically and are not related to logging. Metrics are local to a node, i.e. only a server node will expose how many thin clients are connected to it.